# React Native, why android virtual device showing blank screen?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run my react native app in android virtual device but whenever I run `react-native run-android` it's showing blank screen and when I reload app from server it's show `no device is connected`. Why this is happening? I followed every step from docs, Can someone please help

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening the debugger and checking for errors? On MacOS press ⌘D and on windows press Ctrl+M, then select Remote JS debugging and it should open up in a browser.

Comment: I tried that, but when I press ctrl+m it's just crashing emulator